# MS Excel Formatting Border Using Conditional Formatting or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, formatting

I am new here. I hope you can help me on this. I am having a hardtime in finding a solution for this formatting in Excel. What I want is to achieve a format of a box border in the excel format, where the end border line adjusted automatically when the user is still making an input. Please see the sample photo below as your reference. Thank you very much.

[image: 1]

I have tried this formula in Conditional Formatting

=AND($D8<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=0)
=AND($D8<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=1)

and format border is set on the sides, while bottom border is clear.

I am thinking that cell if cell D* is the last content, the format on this should be bottom border. But after trying and looking for answers, those don't reach my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

| Rule (Formula) | Applies To |
| --- | --- |
| =AND($D1<>"",$D2="") | D2:E15 |
| =D2<>"" | E2:E15 |
| =D2<>"" | D2:E15 |

[image]

[image]